# Google DataStore: how to implement a limit on the number of entries?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Imagine a table containing data for multiple users. How to implement a max number of entry per user?
The problem is that count() requests are costly, and they may timeout if there are a large number of entries.
Is there a best practice for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. What I do is have a property on the users kind (table) that I increment everytime a user makes a post (entry).

You can then check against this number vs. counting all of their entries.

Be sure to use memcache: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/best-practices-for-app-engine-memcache to save database reads/writes.

** Update **

Another option is you can count a keys only query (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries) if the data is in it's own kind (meaning you don't need to specify query parameters).

Quoted from their pricing page (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing):

"Unlimited. Includes calls to allocate Cloud Datastore IDs, keys-only queries, and projection queries that do not use the distinct on clause. A keys-only query or a projection query that does not use the distinct on clause is counted as a single entity read for the query itself. The individual results are counted as small operations."

So you can use a keys-only query to get a count and it will only count as a single entity read. This works really well if you use namespaces (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/multitenancy) over ancestry.

Comment: That would work, the cost being making an additional write request for every create/delete.